# Recover in use apache2.conf

Tags: ubuntu, web-server, apache2

Someone has overwritten an apache2.conf file by accident and they havent restarted or reloaded the server so the old file is still applied.

Is there any way I can recover the previous file / current settings?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's not perfect but `apachectl -S` and `apachectl -M` can give you some of the configuration information. Someone posted a similar problem on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27152943/how-can-i-view-the-complete-httpd-configuration) and one of the answers contains a python script that the author claims will recover the config info. Fair warning, never tried the script so can't speak to the efficacy.